# Strongly typed DataSets and dBase IV on OleDb

Tags: c#, datatable, strongly-typed-dataset, dbase, datatableadapters

I have a strange problem. I created a strongly typed `DataSet` and wanted to add a `TableAdapter`. I did the following steps:

1. Add `TableAdapter`
2. New Connection
   2.1. Set the `DataSource` to .NET Framework-dataprovider for OLE DB
   2.2. OLE DB-Provider: `Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider`
   2.2.1. Opened the datalink-properties of the provider
   2.2.2. Put the folder of the dbf's as Databasename
   2.2.3. Set the Extended Properties to `dBase IV`
   2.2.4. Deleted the Username and set the option 'no password'
   2.2.5. Tested the connection (successfully)
   2.2.6. Closed the properties
   2.3. Tested the connection again (successfully)
   2.4. Clicked OK
3. Clicked Next
4. VS asked me if I wanted to copy the file to my project and I clicked yes
5. I should choose a `CommandType`, but only one option was choosable: Use SQL commands, so I simply clicked next
6. I should use a SQL-command and used the generator to create a simple command where I made this: `SELECT DA_DARFOR, DA_LANGBZ FROM APDARFOR`
   6.1. Under options I unchecked all of this `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`-options, because I only need `SELECT`
   6.2. I clicked next
7. Because I will need the functions of the `DataTables`, I let the `DataTable` fill option active, also the DataTable return-option (Fill and GetData), but I unchecked the `GenerateDBDirectMethods` and clicked next afterwards.
8. I got the message that the `DataTable` and the `TableAdapter` were succesful configured. So I clicked on "Finish".

Then I get the following error-message(I hope I translated it correct):
Error on adding the TableAdapters. Operation for this objecttype not supported.

I don't know what to do. How can I add the dbf(dBase IV)-File to my project, so I can use stongly typed datasets?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. If one of you has the same problem:
First create a connection under "server explorer" -> "dataconnections" -> "add" and afterwards you can create a dataset and pull the table from the serverexplorer to the dataset.